# MySQL and JDBC caching (?) issue with procedure call in Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, stored-procedures, jdbc

I'm working on a project that parses text units (referenced as "ngrams") from a string and stores them in a MySQL database.

In MySQL I have the following procedure that's supposed to store an ngram in a specific dataset (table) if it's not already there and return the id of the ngram:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_ngram`(IN ngram VARCHAR(400), IN dataset VARCHAR(128), OUT ngramId INT)
BEGIN

    -- try get id of ngram
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT `id` INTO @ngramId FROM `mdt_', dataset, '_b1` WHERE `ngram` = ''', ngram, ''' LIMIT 1');
    PREPARE stm FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stm;
    SET ngramId = @ngramId;

    -- if id could not be retrieved
    IF ngramId IS NULL THEN BEGIN
        -- insert ngram into dataset
        SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `mdt_', dataset, '_b1`(`ngram`) VALUES (''', ngram, ''')');
        PREPARE stm FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stm;
        SET ngramId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END;
    END IF;

END$$
```

A dataset table has only two columns: `id`, an auto-incremented int that serves as the primary key, and `ngram`, a `varchar(400)` that serves as a unique index.

In my scala app I have a method that takes in a string, splits it into ngrams and then return a Seq of the ngrams' ids by passing the ngrams to the above procedure:

```
private def processNgrams(text: String, dataSet: String) {
    val ids = parser.parse(text).map(ngram => {
        val query = dbConn.prepareCall("CALL add_ngram(?,?,?)")
        query.setString(1, ngram)
        query.setString(2, dataSet)
        query.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER)
        query.executeUpdate()
        dbConn.commit()
        val id = query.getInt(3)
        Debug(s"parsed ngram - id: $id ${" " * (3 - id.toString.length)}[ $ngram ]")
        id
    }
}
```

`dbConn` in the above code is an instance of `java.sql.Connection` and has auto commit set to false.

When I executed this I noticed that very few ngrams were stored in the database. Here's what the debug statement from the above method prints out:

[image: debug output]

So there are multiple ngrams that are clearly different from each other that seem to have the same id returned from the procedure. If I look in the database table, I can see that for example the ngram "i" has id "1", but it seems that ngrams inserted immediately after also get returned an id of "1". This is true of the other ngrams I looked up in the table as well. This leads me to believe that perhaps the procedure call maybe gets cached?

I've tried a number of things, such as creating the prepared call outside of the method and reusing it and calling clearParameters every time, creating a new call inside the method every time (as it is above), even sleeping the Thread between calls, but nothing seems to make a difference.

I've also tested the procedure by manually running queries in a MySQL client and it seems to run fine, though my program executes queries at a much faster speed than I can manually, so that might make a difference.

I'm not entirely sure if it's a JDBC issue with making the call or a MySQL issue with the procedure. I'm new to scala and MySQL procedures, so forgive me if this is something really simple that's escaped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out, it was the stored procedure causing all the trouble.

In the procedure I check to see if a ngram exists by doing a dynamic SQL query (since the table name is passed in) that stores a value in `@ngramId`, which is a session variable. I store it in `@ngramId` and not into `ngramId` (a procedure output parameter) because prepared statements can only select into session variables (or so I've been told by an error when I originally created the procedure). Next I set the value of `@ngramId` to `ngramId` and check if `ngramId` is null to determine if the ngram exists in the table; if null, the ngram is inserted into the table and `ngramId` is set to the last inserted id.

The problem with this is that because `@ngramId` is a session variable and because I used the same database connection for all procedures calls, the value of @ngramId persisted between calls. So for example, if I made a call with the ngram "I", and it was found in the database with id 1, `@ngramId` now had the value of 1. Next if I tried to insert another ngram that did not exist in the table, the dynamic select statement did not return anything so the value of `@ngramId` remained as 1. Since the output parameter `ngramId` is populated with the value of `@ngramId` and now it was no longer NULL, it bypassed the if statement that inserted the ngram in the database and returned the id of the last ngram found in the table, resulting in the seeming caching of ngram ids.

The solution to this was to add the following line as the very first statement in the procedure:

```
 SET @ngramId = NULL;
```

Which resets the value of `@ngramId` between calls to the procedure over the same session.